# Lagom + LagomPlay - There is no started application

Tags: playframework, lagom

During

```
val value = Play.current.configuration.getString("confKey")
```

An exception or error caused a run to abort: There is no started application 
`java.lang.RuntimeException`: There is no started application

Comment: In Test (Spec) I have no problem with Play.current - this works. But it seems that during startup Lagom context Play application is not running up. I have not any idea how to get LagomApplicationContext from my services I can inject with wire() my implementation of LagomApplicationLoader but how provide configuration object ?

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the global play instance when using `Play.current`. This is incorrect in many cases (during testing you may not have a started application).

You should use dependency injection to inject your configuration.

See: https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/scala/DependencyInjection.html and https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDependencyInjection